# Map array to be conform with a Model in MVVM structure Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swiftui, swift5

I fetch data from Firebase and in this data I have an array of dictionary.

I need to set this array of dictionary in ***days*** conform to StickModel because the key days in HabitModel need to be conform with [StickModel].

But I get this error :

[image: Error]

I use MVVM structure.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class HabitsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var habites = [HabitModel]()
    @Published var days = [StickModel]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        debugPrint("Fetch Data...")
        db.collection("users/" + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)! + "/Habits").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                debugPrint("No document")
                return
            }
            
            self.habites = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> HabitModel in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let progress = data["progress"] as? Float ?? 0
                let start = data["start"] as? String ?? ""
                let end = data["end"] as? String ?? ""
                
                                
                self.days = data["days"].map { myday -> StickModel in
                    
                    let completed = myday["completed"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let dayLetter = myday["day"] as? String ?? ""
                    let progress = myday["progress"] as? Float ?? 0
                    
                    return StickModel(id: UUID().uuidString, progress: progress, completed: completed, day: dayLetter)
                }
                
                
                return HabitModel(id: id, title: title, progress: progress, start: start, end: end, days: self.days)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.days = (data["days"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []).map -> StickModel in
```

Comment: I get the same error...

Comment: Oops! my bad I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Firstore supports Codable, for mapping Firestore documents from/to Swift, which removes the need for manually mapping the individual fields, and makes the whole process much easier to write and less error-prone.

Here is how:

1. Add `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` to your project. You can use either CocoaPods or the Swift Package Manager to do so.
2. Import `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`
3. Conform your type to `Codable`
4. Add an `id` property to your type, and use `@DocumentID` to tell Firestore to map this to the document ID
5. Use `documentReference.data(as: )` to map a document reference to a Swift type
6. Use `documentReference.setData(from: )` to map data from Swift types to a Firestore document
7. (optional, but highly recommended) Implement proper error handling

For more details, check out [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#mapping-arrays)